# Propagating curve on on x-y axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For sending a projectile in my game, I have a curve function in 3D space where the curve propagates on the z axis following the equation:

```
x = this.LinePoints[t - 1].x + xOffset;
y = this.LinePoints[t - 1].y + yOffset;
z = t == 1 ? 0.35f : math.cos(scaleFactor * (t * 0.1f)) * (t * 0.5f);
```

where t goes from 1 to 40 and LinePoints is the line on (x, y) going from a Starting point to an Ending point.

I need to propagate the curve along a combination of the x and y axes from the Starting point to the Ending point (keep the same functions but "rotate" it so the curve is on (x, y)).

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the line described by LinePoints straight? What do you mean by "rotate" the curve - how do you want the 2D trajectory to look? Do you mean that you want the projectile to go between two pre-defined points with the Z-axis formula applied as a "modifier" on an angle?

Comment: Thanks for your support, yes it is a line of 40 points going from a start point (x0, y0, 0) to an end point (x1, y1, 0). I want the resulting curve to be on the (x, y) plane (z = 0).

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide the problem into three parts:

### 1. Making the projectile follow LinePoints

Simple enough. Just add `this.LinePoints[t - 1] - this.LinePoints[t - 2]` to `transform.position` whenever you want the projectile to advance.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float xDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].x - LinePoints[t - 2].x;
    float yDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].y - LinePoints[t - 2].y;

    transform.position += new Vector2(xDiff, yDiff);
    t++;
}
```

### 2. Adding the Z-axis curve without rotation

We need to define a function for the Z-axis curve, and simply apply it on top of the Y axis.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float zDiff = ZFunction(t) - ZFunction(t - 1);

    float xDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].x - LinePoints[t - 2].x;
    float yDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].y - LinePoints[t - 2].y + zDiff;

    transform.position += new Vector2(xDiff, yDiff);
    t++;
}

float ZFunction(int t) {
    if (t == 1) {
        return 0.35f;
    }
    else {
        return Mathf.Cos(scaleFactor * (t * 0.1f)) * (t * 0.5f);
    }
}
```

This will work fine when the Y value of the start and end points are the same.

### 3. Rotating the Z-axis curve

We need to first get the angle between the points, and then get the X and Y elements of the rotation at a certain angle. The X element of an angle is `cos(angle)`, and the Y element is `sin(angle)`. Multiply the value of the Z-function by the trig function for the **opposite** axis, and then add it on top of the position.

You can get the angle using `Vector2.Angle()`, just remember to convert it to radians so it can be taken in by the `Mathf` trig functions.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float angle = Vector2.Angle(startPoint, endPoint) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float zDiff = ZFunction(t) - ZFunction(t - 1);

    float xDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].x - LinePoints[t - 2].x + zDiff * Mathf.Sin(angle);
    float yDiff = LinePoints[t - 1].y - LinePoints[t - 2].y + zDiff * Mathf.Cos(angle);

    transform.position += new Vector2(xDiff, yDiff);
    t++;
}

float ZFunction(int t) {
    if (t == 1) {
        return 0.35f;
    }
    else {
        return Mathf.Cos(scaleFactor * (t * 0.1f)) * (t * 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Note: If you don't need the particular points in `LinePoints`, you should probably ditch the array and get the appropriate positions dynamically. I would recommend looking into `Vector2.Lerp()`, or even better doing the math yourself.

The code is very rough and untested, so comment if you run into any issues.